# Vue.js - How to make sidebar stay open instead of toggling it open?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I have it so the sidebar menu is always open? I don't know the exact whereabouts of the code, but I think it is here somewhere.

https://github.com/arya107/Ask-Arya-Vue-Dashboard/tree/master/src/components/SidebarPlugin

http://user.askarya.ir/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you need to modify the `https://github.com/arya107/Ask-Arya-Vue-Dashboard/blob/master/public/index.html` On this line `19` there is this code `<body class="sidebar-mini">` remove the `sidebar-mini` class. This will show the sidebar on all pages.

For your second question, you can add method then add that method to @click on the template's button like this:

```
<template>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" @click="changeLang">Change Language</button>   
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {

        ...
        changeLang(){
            this.i18n = this.$i18n;
            this.i18n.locale = 'ar';
            this.$rtl.enableRTL();
        }
        ...
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank youuu! :D

Comment: Can you also advise me on how to enable this piece of code in a button so I can switch languages? The dashboard already has RTL support and I think this is the class.............  :class="$rtl.isRTL

Comment: `https://github.com/arya107/Ask-Arya-Vue-Dashboard/blob/master/src/pages/Pages/RTLPage.vue` by looking at this file. It seems you can add the code `this.$rtl.enableRTL()` on component's mounted().  I believe it will enable RTL for the whole page. By the way, the last question seems to be off topic.

Comment: how I could program this piece of code, so that I can have a button in my Navbar to switch languages?

Comment: I updated my answer, you probably need to create a method then add this `this.i18n.locale = 'ar'` then call on `@click` on your button.

Answer (score 3):

Just put the "**visible**" prop in your  tag like so:

<b-sidebar **visible**>

It will remain open.

And to not close it on route change add **noCloseOnRouteChange** prop. To remove the close button, add **noHeader** prop.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS-file:

```
.sidebar-mini .sidebar:hover {
  width: 260px !important;
}

.sidebar-mini .main-panel>.content, .sidebar-mini footer {
  padding-left: 310px !important;
}
```

But that only fixes it on Desktop-devices.

Comment: The short answer: No. :-) You need to find the/a CSS-file and add those lines. At least not if you want to make this change, this way. And I can't find anything in the documentation about it. If the developers have made a setting for it, then maybe you can. But I can't find it, by first glance.

Comment: it is really strange that I can't make it open by default.

Comment: Can you also advise me on how to enable this piece of code in a button so I can switch languages? The dashboard already has RTL support and I think this is the class............. :class="$rtl.isRTL

Answer (score 0):

`showSidebar: false,`

Try setting that to true.

https://github.com/arya107/Ask-Arya-Vue-Dashboard/blob/master/src/components/SidebarPlugin/index.js

Comment: @AryaD Give a little more info then. Is the sidemenu initially open and closes when clicking on an item?